# Misaligned flag button on questions

Tags: bug, questions, user-interface, post-menu

This might be the tiniest bug ever but there seems to be an extra space between follow or close and flag on questions.

This shot is from this site.

> [image]

This one is from a site where I have close too.

> [image]

You can see, there are three spaces, not two between the last two options.

A bit of looking around seems to show that this occurs when the delete button is not present and questions with the delete option show fine.