# Extra space showing up after the "follow" button on answers

Tags: bug, design

There seems to be an extra space showing up after the "follow" button - in between "follow" and "flag" (or "delete") on answers. This is happening both on sites where I have delete vote privileges and sites where I do not.

For instance, from Interpersonal.SE (where I can vote to delete answers):

[image: share edit follow (extra space) flag]

...and with a delete vote, where it is still showing up:

[image: share edit follow (extra space) delete(1) flag]

And also on Puzzling.SE, where I cannot vote to delete answers:

[image: share edit follow (extra space) flag]

This doesn't appear to be happening on questions, only answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too much space between links in post menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347995/too-much-space-between-links-in-post-menu) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348221/misaligned-flag-button-on-questions Strange you don't see this on answers, I see it everywhere and once you see it, you can't forget it.